# Accessing CodeIgniter app from sibling subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, dry

I'm having a scenario where I had to deploy multiple directories for different languages. Development has initially centered on one of those languages, and just one part of the whole site is a small CI app.

I'm trying to avoid copying the whole app for the several other languages, and redirecting to it with an `.htacces`. The latter is working fine, but CI returns a 404 error when accessed from a URL different to the *real* one.

My best guess is that certain configuration files must exist with unique properties that configure the additional root URLs, but I don't know where to start (and Google didn't come up with a similar scenario).

File Structure:

```
public_html/
    lang1/
        app/    
            (the actual CI app)
        other static stuff...
    lang2/
        app/
            .htaccess (redirecting to /lang1/app/)
        other static stuff...
    lang3/
        ...
```

Additional info:

The `$config['base_url']` is set to `http://.../lang1/app/`.

The `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lang1/app/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I'm thinking maybe copying the root index.php and modifying it to refer to the right directory could be the answer after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by my own. For those who might find this question in the future, these are the steps to access your application from a different directory. Considering the scenario introduced in the question above, the following example will work for the deployment of of a *ghost* version of the app in the `lang2` directory:

1.- **Copy** *only* the index.php file from the root of your CI installation (from `lang1/app/index.php`) to the `lang2/app/` directory.

2.- **Edit** the following lines:

```
$system_path = '../../lang1/app/system';


$application_folder = '../../lang1/app/application';
//Even if the documentation suggests the necessity of a _full path_, 
//this works perfectly well for 2.1.0
```

3.- **Add** any configuration you may want to have set explicitly for said subdirectory, these will be set to $this->config, replacing the values set in the config file in your base application:

```
$assign_to_config['lang_version'] = 'lang2';
```

4.- You have to set a proper `base_url`. In this case, we could reuse the `lang_version` config we just included. This way, we can forget about this line in the next languages we need to create.

```
$assign_to_config['base_url'] = 
    'http://www.example.com/' . $assign_to_config['lang_version'] . '/app/';
```

5.- **Create** an `.htaccess` file inside `lang2/app` to make sure that any static assets (js, css, images) accessed by the HTML are get from the actual assets folder inside the original app directory, like in `lang1/app/assets`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /lang1/app/assets/$1 [L]
```

6.- **Add** to this `.htaccess` your usual rule to keep your URLs friendly, but this time directing all traffic to the *ghost* copy of your app:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lang2/app/index.php/$1 [L]
```

7.- **Grab a beer** or any other beverage you drink to celebrate success, always respecting your local laws. Profit. Your controllers will have to read the `config('lang_version')` value to present the content in the proper language to the user. You may use the included language helper for that, or any other solution you prefer.

Comment: What?! CodeIgniter has a language helper. Why don't you use that? Does each language have like different views, modals, and/or controllers?

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky the files are not actually being duplicated. What this gives you is site.com/es site.com/de etc.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky The language helper has only string functions. The problem came from the nature of the filesystem. You can use it afterwards to fix the actual strings. I made some edits to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do this? Theres a thing called i18n.

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/CodeIgniter_2.1_internationalization_i18n/

Why not use this? Didnt copying the app folders seem a bit tedious to you? Theres a language helper for a reason.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly, I _didn't_ want to copy the app folders. As mentioned above, it's not actually a problem of strings that have to be translated. The static part of the website (some pure html stuff) was already duplicated and translated itself. 
I needed to add a dynamic section for each language _and actually used the language helper_ in it. As @Robert pointed out before, this allows you to have several different `base_url()`'s, one for each language, that trigger the i18n helper, and to preserve the original folder structure of the static stuff.